# Angularjs Check Array before Push with NG-Disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-storage

Each dress is assigned an ID, the dress ID can be found within the `$StateParams` function and the page URL - e.g #/dresses/21.

When the user clicks the Heart (Like) or Broken Heart (Dislike) button the dress ID is placed within the localstorage Heart/Broken Heart array - see below.

Also, when either button has been clicked the button disables itself, preventing multiple dress ID's being pushed! This can be reverted by clicking the opersit button.

**The problem!**
I can't figure out how to prevent submits the same dress ID after refreshing the page - I tried searching the array before pushing the dress ID but this didn't work. Also, I'm able to prevent double dress ID's from being submitted by preventing double clicks, but if I refresh the page the button is able to push dress ID's to the array although it already has the dress ID present!

Any guidance would help massively!
Thank you.

**DESIGN:**
[image]
**HTML:**

```
<ul class="railcontrols">
  <li>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-fab md-mini" ng-click="heart()" ng-dblclick="return false;" ng-disabled="heartflag">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="svg/heart.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-fab md-mini" ng-click="brokenheart()" ng-dblclick="return false;" ng-disabled="brokenheartflag">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="svg/brokenheart.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
   fittingApp.controller('railsCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$stateParams','$filter', function($scope, $localStorage, $stateParams, $filter) {
      $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
      var dressID = $stateParams.id;
      if ($scope.$storage.userLoveList === undefined) {
        var getUserID = $scope.$storage.profileData.userID;
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList = ({
          'userID': getUserID,
          'heart': [],
          'brokenheart': []
        });
      }
      $scope.heartflag = false;
      $scope.heart = function() {
        $scope.heartflag = true;
        $scope.brokenheartflag = false;
        // Push Heart
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList.heart.push({'dressID': dressID});
        // Remove BrokenHeart
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList.brokenheart = $filter('filter')($scope.$storage.userLoveList.brokenheart, {dressID: '!'+dressID});
      };
      $scope.brokenheartflag = false;
      $scope.brokenheart = function() {
        $scope.brokenheartflag = true;
        $scope.heartflag = false;
        // Push Broken Heart
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList.brokenheart.push({'dressID': dressID});
        // Remove Heart
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList.heart = $filter('filter')($scope.$storage.userLoveList.heart, {dressID: '!'+dressID});
      };
    }]);
```

**OUTPUT {{$storage | json}}**

```
{
  "userLoveList": {
    "userID": "1",
    "heart": [
      {
        "dressID": "21",
        "dressID": "21", // Prevent Duplicates
        "dressID": "19"
      }
    ],
    "brokenheart": [
     {
        "dressID": "10"
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like it would be  simpler if `heart` arrays were just id values (not objects) ... then check `indexOf()` for that id value. Otherwise have to iterate array for each `dressId`

Comment: @charlietfl If I tweak the Array would this then be able to check the Array before pushing? also, would this then help the button remeber its state e.g if its been clicked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code something like this:

```
fittingApp.controller('railsCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$stateParams', function($scope, $localStorage, $stateParams) {
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
    var dressID = $stateParams.id;
    if ($scope.$storage.userLoveList === undefined) {
        var getUserID = $scope.$storage.profileData.userID;
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList = ({
            'userID': getUserID,
            'heart': [],
            'brokenheart': []
        });
    }

    function remove(list, value) {
        var index = list.indexOf(value);
        if (index > -1) {
            list.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    $scope.heartflag = $scope.$storage.userLoveList.heart.indexOf(dressID) > -1;
    $scope.brokenheartflag = $scope.$storage.userLoveList.brokenheart.indexOf(dressID) > -1;

    $scope.heart = function() {
        $scope.heartflag = true;
        $scope.brokenheartflag = false;
        // Push Heart
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList.heart.push(dressID);

        // Remove BrokenHeart
        remove($scope.$storage.userLoveList.brokenheart, dressID);
    };

    $scope.brokenheart = function() {
        $scope.heartflag = false;
        $scope.brokenheartflag = true;
        // Push Broken Heart
        $scope.$storage.userLoveList.brokenheart.push(dressID);
        // Remove Heart
        remove($scope.$storage.userLoveList.heart, dressID);
    };
}]);
```

Here is what happening:

We are first checking if we already have the `dressID` in either list of `heart` or `brokenheart` so that we can disable the particular buttons. Now since we have already disabled the particular button, user will not be  able to click is twice.